# Rails 3 - Nested Resources Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have users, and then each user has one mailbox where they're delivered messages. My routes.rb looks something like:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :mailboxes 
  end
```

If I do a rake route, I see this route available to me:

```
user_mailbox GET    /users/:user_id/mailboxes/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"mailboxes"}
```

I wanted to link to this path in my application layout, in a sort of toolbar the user finds at the top of the screen.

My view code is:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("mail_icon.png", :id => 'mail_notice'), user_mailbox_path(current_user)%>
```

The problem I'm having is that I get a routing error for this path if I'm nothing withing users/* - So anywhere else in my application besides the resource my mailbox is nested under. If I'm on, lets say my user's index page, the path does work without issue.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"mailboxes",
```

Is there something I could be missing with this route? Anything related to users works, it's just the mailbox that I'm having issues with.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like mailbox should be a singleton resource.

```
resources :users do
  resource :mailbox
end
```

Otherwise it would expect that a user has multiple mailboxes and you'd have to provide the `mailbox_id` to `user_mailbox_path` as well.

```
user_mailbox_path(current_user, @mailbox)
```

Comment: Doh, thanks a ton for the help. Probably the 2nd or 3rd time I've messed that up over the last few months. Shame on me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the route:

```
user_mailbox GET    /users/:user_id/mailboxes/:id(.:format)
```

you need to provide two ids, the :user_id and the :id of the mailbox. This makes sense if the user can have several mailboxes.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("mail_icon.png", :id => 'mail_notice'), 
            user_mailbox_path(current_user, current_user.mailboxes.first) %>
```

If you intend the user to have only one mailbox, then I would change the routes.rb like this:

```
resources :users do
  get :mailbox, :on => :member 
end
```

and you would get a route like:

```
mailbox_user   GET    /users/:id/mailbox(.:format)
```

which would be handled by the `mailbox` method on `UsersController`, and you can get the path to it in your views with `mailbox_user_path(current_user)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help jorge. Bonehead mistake on my part only passing the user. I truly appreciate the help. I also like the suggestion of using mailbox as just a method to keep things trim.