# Rails nested routing go wildly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Two models: `Window`(belongs_to :window_input) and `WindowInput`(has_many :windows), when I put this in routes.rb:

```
resources :window_inputs do
    resource :window
end
```

the `rake routes` result is:

```
new_window_inputs_window GET    /window_inputs/windows/new(.:format)
```

The right routing should be: `/window_inputs/:window_input_id/windows/new(.:format)`. I wonder this error comes from the two models' names. I use sqlite and rails 3.2.2 . Any one can help me on this?

Comment: It's my fault. Forgot the 's' :`resource*s* :window`.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353023/rails-3-nested-resources-routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget when nesting to declare the second resource as a child of the first:

```
resources :window_inputs do |window_inputs|
  window_inputs.resources :windows
end
```

It's declared as simply namespaced, not dependent, unless you refer to it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I go the way: `resources :window_inputs do 
   resources :windows 
  end`